# Nested loop for Distance Matrix

Tags: python, nested-loops

array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Desired output is somehow Distance Matrix (with 0 values on diagonal).

I want to module(average[0] - average[1]) and etc. with for loop or nested loop.

Ex:

```
1-1,1-2,1-3,1-4,1-5
2-1,2-2,2-3,2-4,2-5
...
```

And then store it somewhere

Comment: Can you please post some details of code what you have tried earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
size = len(a)
b = [[0 for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)] 
for i in range(0,size):
   for j in range(0,size):
       b[i][j] = (a[i]-a[j])
print(b)
```

b array is your desired distance matrix

Comment: I think you meant `abs(a[i]-a[j])`

Comment: Distance Matrix indeed have absolute values. But as per @Mamed 's example he want them negative.